# Any easy way to merge, flattern and concat multiple multi-dimensional arrays in javascript in a certain way (right to left)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

I need an easy way to merge, flattern and concat multiple multi-dimensional arrays in javascript in a certain way (right to left)

```
# Exemple
[['.class1', '.class2'], ['.class3', ['.class4', '.class5', ...], ['.class6'], ...]]
# OR
[['.class1', '.class2'], ['.class3', ['.class4', '.class5', ...]], ['.class6'], ...]

# Would become
['.class1.class3.class4.class6', '.class1.class3.class5.class6', '.class2.class3.class4.class6', '.class2.class3.class5.class6', ...]
```

I've found the reduceRight function from underscore.js lib but I'm not sure how i could acheive this easily as it needs to be done recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [['.class1', '.class2'], ['.class3', ['.class4', '.class5'], ['.class6']]];

function cartesian(a, b) {                                  // return the cartesian product of the two arrays a and b
  if(!a.length) return b;                                   // if a is empty then the result of the product is b
  if(!b.length) return a;                                   // if b is empty then the product is a
  
  return a.reduce((res, ae) => (b.forEach(be => res.push(ae + be)), res), []); // product of non-empty a and non-empty b
}

function combos(arr) {                                      // take an array arr and return the combinations out from its nested arrays
  if(arr.every(e => !Array.isArray(e))) return arr;         // if the array doesn't contain any nested arrays then return it as it is

  return arr.reduce((acc, e) => {                           // otherwise return the cartesian product of all its elements
    e = Array.isArray(e)? combos(e): [e];                   // if the current element is an array, then get its combos, otherwise, wrap it in an array
    return cartesian(acc, e);                               // get the cartesian product of previous elements and the combos of this element e
  }, []);
}

console.log(combos(data));
```

Comment: I really like this one because it's surely simple to understand, and also allow to pass [['.class1'], [], '.class2'], great work

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for variable length of parts with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

This version works now with nested arrays and flats it in advanced.

```js
function combine(array) {
    function c(part, index) {
        var temp = array[index];

        if (Array.isArray(temp) && temp.some(function (a) { return Array.isArray(a); })) {
            temp = combine(array[index].map(function (a) { return Array.isArray(a) ? a : [a]; }));
        }
        temp.forEach(function (a) {
            var p = part.concat(a);
            if (p.length === array.length) {
                r.push(p.join(''));
                return;
            }
            c(p, index + 1);
        });
    }

    var r = [];

    c([], 0);
    return r;
}

var array = [
        ['.class1', '.class2'],
        ['.class3',
            ['.class4', '.class5'],
            ['.class6']
        ]
    ],
    result = combine(array);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I believe OP's data is supposed to look like this: `[['.class1', '.class2'], ['.class3', ['.class4', '.class5']], ['class6']]`. class4 and class5 should be nested inside the array containing class3, which makes this problem a bit more difficult to solve

Comment: @mhodges, i get the same result as op requested. what is wrong with the assumption of a single `'.class'`3? the result of your nested data could be different than requested.

Comment: "merge, flattern and concat multiple **multi-dimensional arrays**" You are not using any multi-dimensional arrays, and when you plug in data that does use them, it does not return the desired result.

Comment: I needed multidimensional arrays, so this solution is partly working at the moment. But it helps a lot, thanks ;)

Comment: @user1855153, please edit the question and give a valid array.

Comment: @NinaScholz Looks great =)

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), which is a better version of underscore (imo), this can be expressed fairly simply using `flattenDeep` (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flattenDeep) on each element of your multi-dimensional array:

```
function combine(list) {
  const arrays = list.map(_.flattenDeep);
  return arrays.map((a) => a.join('');
}
```